# IBM X3850 does not boot from internal USB by default unless startup boot menu is visited

Tags: vmware-esxi, ibm-xseries, usb-boot

I'm running Vmware ESXI from the internal USB.

No matter how many times I persist the boot order so that the server boots from the internal USB, the server starts up with a blinking line cursor and does nothing.

However if during the preboot I press F12 and then select the internal USB, it successfully boots from it. But it looks like it never remembers it for the next time. I have tried this using soft reboot and hard ones which all ended up in the blinking server mode.  I thought this could be a CMOS battery issue. I replaced the battery today and it made absolutely no difference.

Because  of this I'm not able to detach the keyboard and memory from the server which is not convenient at all.

How do I get the BIOS to persist the "boot from USB" option?

Comment: While I think I see what you're getting at, this isn't actually phrased as a question.  What problem are you trying to solve by booting from USB?  (The manufacturer may assume that you only want to boot from USB once, to install an OS, and never again.)

Comment: Vmware ESXI from the internal USB. This is a very common scenario. n fact IBM ships servers like that when requested

Comment: And what does the manual say about boot order?  And what do IBM support say?

Comment: Sorry but your comment is too generic. 
And i don't have IBM support. If I did I wouldn't be posting my question here!

Comment: Further note on this problem:
The normal boot order does not have an option for booting from embedded USB. I have to use F12 for that only

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant for you, but I was in the same situation as you and believe that the internal SAS controller intercepts the boot process. Do the lights on the hard disk trays blink when the boot process gets stuck?

If so and given that you want to boot from USB anyways, you can try to disable the controller for booting. You can disable booting either from the SAS configuration (CTRL-C when it boots the controllor) or by setting the PCI boot preference in the normal BIOS from *SAS Planar* to an empty PCI slot. This workaround helped me to persistently boot to the (internal) USB drive with the x3850 M2.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. 
Yes it sounds like this could solve my problem. For now I'm booting from disk but I'd like to boot my ESXI from a USB. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Disabling booting from the SAS configuration was all that was necessary for me. After making the usbkey the persistant boot device in the boot menu (f12) esxi booted without any input from me.
x3850 M2 owner.